# How to pass a list as multiple variables in scipy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I am new to python, and I can't find a solution to my problem since I am not even really sure what I am looking for or what I should search for in google.

I have a dataframe with 30 columns and I want to do a Friedman test with scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare

As an argument I need all the samples which are my df's columns.

I tried various methods but I can't figure it out:

```
scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare(df)
```

```
lst_cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3',..., 'col30']
scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare(df[lst_cols])
```

```
lst_cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3',..., 'col30']
samples = []
for i in lst_cols:
    lst = df[i].tolist()
    samples.append(lst)

scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare(samples)
```

But I always get the Error: At least 3 sets of samples must be given for Friedman test, got 1

I get that that I seem to always pass a single list / single df. How can I use the elements of a list as seperate samples?

greetings

Answer (score 1):

When calling a function that takes multiple arguments, you can use a list (or any sequence really) as separate arguments with the `*` operator:

```py
def foo(a, b):
    return a+b
    
l = [1, 2]

# unpacks l i to a and b
foo(*l)
```

So just stick a `*` in front of your columns:

```
scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare(*df[lst_cols])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `*` before list, it expands list to values

```
lst_cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3',..., 'col30']
samples = []
for i in lst_cols:
    lst = df[i].tolist()
    samples.append(lst)

scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare(*samples)
```

or even simple

```
scipy.stats.friedmanchisquare(*df.values)
```